# Is it bad to have "foreign key redundancy" in a database?

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database structure with the following simplified example:

```
Team has many members
Member has many clients
Client has many projects
```

Assuming my objects have these parameters:

```
Team: id, type
Member: id, team_id, name
Client: id, member_id, email
Project: id, client_id
```

It's simple enough to find a project's client, or a client's member, or a member's team.

However, assuming I want to find a project's team, for example, I have to first find a project's client, then a client's member, and then the member's team.

I could add a team_id directly to the project, like this:

```
Project: id, client_id, team_id
```

I realize, however, this adds a certain level of redundancy since that information *is* available by "going up the relationship tree." Is that a bad idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you mean "Each team member has many clients", and "Each team member's client has many projects"?

Comment: What do you consider "harmful redundancy"? Are you talking about the same kind of "harmful redudancy" that normalization theory deals with? Or is your measure of what is "harmful" a different measure?

Answer (score 2):

Whether this is a bad idea or not depends on the typical use cases for the database.

Adding additional foreign keys increases the cost of modifying the structure (INSERT, UPDATE if modifying relationships, DELETE).

*Not* having the additional foreign keys increases the cost of queries that would otherwise benefit from their presence.

If the project structure does not change very much but you do query the structure frequently, the extra foreign key is likely to be a net positive.  If in doubt, create the structure with reasonable test data and benchmark some queries you think will be typical.

Comment: You don't have to add FKs. You can simply make the FKs composite.

Comment: Still, the larger the keys you manage, the slower are updates.  Even if you have a wider key, you will still fit fewer keys on a disk page and you can cache fewer keys in available RAM.

Answer (score 1):

It's not like you have to do 4 queries here.  You just do a join that joins all tables in a single query.  This does not add a lot of complexity, but it does add a little.  I would just go with what you have.