# Should I decrease the joining tables number but increase the data or reverse

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnM4g.png)

I'm still a student, and I have a practical question. I have 4 tables (class {one to many to} subject {one to many to} lecture) and (teacher {one to many to } lecture). If I want to get all classes that some teachers teach in, I have to make 3 inner joins.

Is it correct to do it that way, or should I connect also (class { one to many } lectures) and by that I would decrease the joins numbers to two, but increase the table field by putting another foreign key. Which is better, to decrease the joining, but increase data, or the reverse?

Comment: You should work with the model that best fits your needs.

Comment: This is a good question and shouldn't be getting downvotes. It is already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856022/is-it-bad-to-have-foreign-key-redundancy-in-a-database

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much  about joins, it's far more important to have a clear table structure and to avoid duplicate data.

if columns are indexed properly (with the proper key for  each table) the joins shouldn't be as costly as you think.